# node.js jade if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I write a demo of node.js and try to use jade template, like the following code:

```
if name == 'a'
  block header
    h4 statement1
else
  block header
    h4 statement2
```

'name' is a parameter that is passed to the template and the template file extend other template, so I try to show something in block 'header'.
 But I find it always show statement1 content even if 'name' is undefined or any other value. 
I've test that name's value is passed properly, so it seems 'if' statement not works in my code. How can I get this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this instead. It should work:

```
block header
   if name == 'a'
      h4 statement1
   else
      h4 statement2
```

From what I understand it has something to do with the fact that Jade resolves extends before it resolves conditionals. If you do like this:

```
if true
   append header
      h4 hello
else
   append header
      h4 world
```

Jade appends both "hello" and "world" even though that should be impossible because the if statement is clearly true. This further illustrates that the conditional is not evaluating how to handle the extensions properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works. But this means when 'if' statement needs to do something with several blocks, I should write 'if' statement for each block, instead of using the same 'if' statement, right?

Comment: Well, yes. Depends a bit on how your code is structured I guess. But you need to put your conditionals inside of your extends and that makes it hard for two blocks to share an if statement.